# mirrorring ipod screen on external monitor

Tags: ios4

I would like to display the ipod screen on an external display. For this I create two instance of UIWindow and add the my view controllers view as subview of these windows. But it is displaying only on external window.

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[externalWindow addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[externalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

Is it not possible to add the same view on both windows? How can make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying to do the same thing for the iPad and I found this, http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123. Its a class that you can add to your project that will do the screen mirroring for you. He says it has been designed for and tested on the iPad and iPhone 4 but should work on devices using sdk 4.0 and above.